# Django model.save() not writing to database

Tags: database, django, save, django-forms

I'm new to Django and just trying to submit a form using ModelForms to create a new event and save it to the database.

I am trying to insert rows into three tables: Location, Event (which has a location_id FK), and EventSchedule (which as an event_id FK).

Here is the method that saves the forms. When it is called, no errors are returned, yet the new rows are not inserted into the database.:

**addNewEvent()** (in views.py)

```
def addNewEvent(self, event_form, location_form, event_sched_form, latitude, longitude):

    new_event = event_form.save(commit=False)
    new_location = location_form.save(commit=False)
    new_event_sched = event_sched_form.save(commit=False)
    # set any necessary values and save forms
    new_location.latitude = latitude
    new_location.longitude = longitude
    new_location.save()
    new_event.flagged = False
    new_event.location = new_location
    new_event.save()
    new_event_sched.event = new_event
    new_event_sched.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'location'

class Event(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = (
        ('KID', 'Kids'),
        ('FAM', 'Family'),
        ('NIT', 'Nightlife'),
        ('OUT', 'Outdoors'),
        ('ART', 'Arts'),
        ('MSC', 'Music'),
        ('SPT', 'Sports'),
        ('SAL', 'Sale'),
        ('EDU', 'Educational'),
        ('POL', 'Political'),
        ('FOD', 'Food'),
        ('OTH', 'Other')
    )
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORIES)
    age_req = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    cost_per_person = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    flagged = models.BooleanField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserEvent')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'event'

class EventSchedule(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'event_schedule'
```

**forms.py**

from django.forms import ModelForm, forms
from models import Event, Location, EventSchedule

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('name','description','category','age_req','cost_per_person')

class LocationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('name','city','state_code','zip','country')

class EventScheduleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EventSchedule
        fields = ('start_date_time', 'end_date_time')
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you,

Peter

**EDIT:**

I can't even save a Model, let alone a ModelForm (even though I am doing it successfully in other places). I added the following code to associate a user with an event. No errors, yet it doesn't add a row to the database:

```
new_user_event = UserEvent(user=user,
                                event=new_event,
                                datetime_created=datetime.datetime.now())
new_user_event.save()
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**

Screenshot of new_user_event: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHnmR.jpg

**EDIT 3:**

This is how I'm instantiating the ModelForms:

```
event_form = EventForm(request.POST or None)
location_form = LocationForm(request.POST or None)
event_sched_form = EventScheduleForm(request.POST or None)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Wow, I am such an idiot. I was deleting the rows in the tables before I could actually display the events due to some code that populated the database with dummy data.

Can I delete this question or should it live on as a testament to my stupidity?

Comment: If it makes you feel better, this question/answer helped us debug a similar situation on our Jenkins server. So your answer has helped at least one person!

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

`commit=false` is the cause

Comment: But I save it after I do the initial save with commit=False (i.e. new_location.save())... Doesn't that actually save it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the most import part here IHMO : how are your forms instanciated ? A ModelForm can be used to both create a new instance or update an existing one. If you pass existing instances to your forms, then your code will only update them.

Comment: Oh! Well, I don't have access to the code at the moment, but I think I did it like this:

`event_form = EventForm(request.POST or None)`